# Rails: Why does embedding video work with & without protocol (http)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, iframe, src

Why do both these work when embedding a video iframe in a Rails application?

```
<iframe src="//player.vimeo.com/video/...>
```

and

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/...>
```

Please enlighten me. I've seen it both ways. Which is preferable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `//` infers the protocol from the URL from which the root page is served.  Navigating to a site `https://yoursite.com` would mean all `//` links would also be served using HTTPS.  This can be helpful if you're running the same page in a local environment that is using HTTP, and don't want to change it when pushing it to a production environment served using HTTPS.